# Shairport make error on RetroPie

Tags: retropie, shairplay

Following the Readme instructions (as well as other websites), I get some errors when using the `make` command while building Shairport. I configure it and it all seems okay:

```
pi@retropie ~/shairport $ sudo ./configure
Configuring Shairport
OpenSSL found
libao found
PulseAudio found
ALSA found
Avahi client found
getopt.h not found
CFLAGS: -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/alsa -D_REENTRANT
LDFLAGS: -lm -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto -lao -lpulse-simple -lpulse -lasound -lavahi-common -lavahi-client
Configure successful. You may now build with 'make'
```

But when I do the `make` command, I get an error and I cannot figure out the problem:

```
pi@retropie ~/shairport $ sudo make
cc -c -O2 -Wall -D_REENTRANT   -I/usr/include/alsa   -D_REENTRANT   shairport.c
cc1: error: /usr/local/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf: Not a directory
cc1: warning: /usr/local/include: not a directory [enabled by default]
Makefile:60: recipe for target 'shairport.o' failed
make: *** [shairport.o] Error 1
```

My best guess is that there is something missing in RetroPie.

https://github.com/abrasive/shairport

Comment: Also, I just found out that it isn't just shairport, it's any time I try to use the `make` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

In the `/usr/local` directory were two files, `include` and `lib`. I deleted the two files and re-ran the `make` command and it all worked well. I guess it cannot create directories with the same names as files in a directory.

Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977657/cc1-error-usr-local-include-not-a-directory-after-installing-c-library).

Comment: Yeah, `/usr/local/include` and `lib` should have been directories from the start (but they would have been empty), owned root-root and set 0755 (you can check this with `stat`, but if `sudo make` made them it should be fine).   Something weird must have happened at some point...